# yoast seo plugin is not working in Bridge wordpress theme how can i solve this problem

Tags: wordpress

yoast seo plugin is not working in Bridge wordpress theme how can i solve this problem, plz help me

Comment: Please check here - https://qode.ticksy.com/ticket/445687

Comment: and join this group for better solution - https://themeforest.net/item/bridge-creative-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7315054/comments?page=270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your theme function.php

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

Comment: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/the-seo-title-output-for-the-plugin-doesnt-work-as-expected/